# Iterating Through Numpy Array, Element Value Causing Out of Bounds?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I know this is something stupid... but I'm missing it. I'm trying to fill a numpy array with random values (1-10) and then iterate through the array to check those values. If I fill the array with values 1-9... no problem, if one of the values is ever 10... I get an out of bounds error.

When iterating through an array using:

```
for x in array:
     if array[x]==y: do_something_with_x
```

Is x not the element in the array? If that's the case, why is my code referencing *the value of x* as 10 and causing the array to go out of bounds?

```
import numpy as np
import random

arr_orig = np.zeros(10)
arr_copy = np.copy(arr_orig)

arr_orig = np.random.randint(1,11,10)

lowest_val = arr_orig[0]

for x in arr_orig:
    if arr_orig[x] < lowest_val: lowest_val = arr_orig[x] 

arr_copy[0] = lowest_val

print (arr_orig)
print (arr_copy)
```

Comment: `for x in array` This gives you the _values_ in the array, not the _indexes_.  So if the value 10 is in the array, you eventually try to access `array[10]`, and you get the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As in the comment from @John Gordon, it's an indexing problem. I think you meant:

```
for x in arr_orig:
    if x < lowest_val: lowest_val = x
```